# Xamarin Forms StyleClass Binding

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to be able to change the *StyleClass* of an element through the equivalent of 
`IsParentSelect ? "Selected" : ""`, to change the button appearance with CSS. So, I made a Converter to do this for me.

However, I've been having a headache trying to figure out why the Binding isn't working for the *StyleClass* attribute, because it does work for the attribute *Text*.

I'm getting a NullPointerException in LightLambda Class when using the Binding on the StyleClass attribute.

Anyone have an idea why I'm getting this Exception?

Thank you very much!

**The Resources**

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <StyleSheet Source="../Styles/Styles.css" />
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:BoolConverter x:Key="boolConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

**The Binding:**

`<Button StyleClass="{Binding IsParentSelected, Converter={StaticResource boolConverter}, ConverterParameter=Selected}" />`

**The ViewModel**

```
public class IdentificationViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public IdentificationViewModel()
    {
        Title = "Identification";
        IsParentSelected = true;
    }

    bool isParentSelected = false;
    public bool IsParentSelected
    {
        get { return isParentSelected; }
        set { SetProperty(ref isParentSelected, value); }
    }

}
```

**The Converter**

```
public class BoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var s = ((string)parameter).Split(':');

        if ((bool)value)
            return s[0].Trim();
        if (s.Length > 1)
            return s[1].Trim();
        return String.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var s = ((string)parameter).Split(':');
        return (string)value == s[0].Trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: From the looks of it, `StyleClass` is not a bindable property

Comment: Ahhh... I see... going through Page and VisualElement classes, there are quite a few properties that aren't bindable... It's unfortunate :( Thanks Gerald.